# How to implement collision avoidance on serial port

Tags: c++, serial-port, collision-detection

I have many devices that communicate through COM port(tty/s0), i need to implement collision avoidance to make collision impossible. Please give me some algorithm or code.

Using: smart6818(Friendly arm), Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

I've found out this controller allows a CSMA/CA medium access. Before sending a packet, it sends some kind of acknowledgment frames (ACK, NACK or BUSY). But I do not know how to implement this

Comment: If your use case allows it, you can setup a master-slave configuration. You'd have one master device and several slave devices. Information from the slave devices is only sent, when the master asks for it. So you can send a request from the master to a slave and only send the next until you received the answer. This won't work, if your use case does not allow polling.

Comment: @eike, In my case, this is impossible because all devices are independent of each other can communicate with the controller. 
I need to somehow look at the condition of the bus, is it free or not

Comment: It's enough if they all depend on the controller. Just make the controller the master device and all others slaves. The only problem with this is, the controller would have to poll the other devices for info.

Comment: @eike, I do not have access to the controller to make it like a master. This controller communicates with another controller and I have two devices that poll the controller and get a response. I've found out this controller allows a CSMA/CA medium access. Before sending a packet, it sends some kind of acknowledgment frames (ACK, NACK or BUSY). But I do not know how to implement this

Comment: In that case, I would add these details to your question and hope for someone to answer this. I sadly can't help you here.

Comment: Is using RS-485 an option? (It can easily be electrically converted from RS232) With these you can implement many CD/CA algorithms without issue.